# htaccess - Redirect from domain.com/index.php to domain.com?

Tags: mod-rewrite, .htaccess

is it possible to do a rewrite rule in a htaccess that redirects from www.example.com/index.php, to www.example.com?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am assuming that index.php is not the DocumentRoot for www.example.com and therefore you are just redirecting to the DocumentRoot.  If so, use the following:

```
Redirect 301 /index.php http://www.example.com
```